# Django Many to Many Relationship Add Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm using Django's ManyToManyField for one of my models.

```
class Requirement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Course(models.Model):
    requirements = models.ManyToManyField(Requirement)
```

I want to be able to assign requirements for my classes, so to do that, I try the following: I get a class, course, that is already saved or that I have just saved, and I run the following:

```
c = Course.objects.get(title="STACK 100")
req = Requirement.objects.get(name="XYZ")
c.requirements.add(req)
```

While this works when I do it through the Django manage.py shell, it does not work when I do it programatically in a script. I work with other models in this script and that all works fine. And I even know it successfully retrieves the current course and the requirement as I check both. I can't figure out what the problem is!

EDIT:

What I mean by not working is that, the requirements field of the course remains empty. For example, if i do c.requirements.all(), I'll get an empty list. However, if I do this approach through the shell, the list will be populated. The script is a crawler that uses BeautifulSoup to crawl a website. I try to add requirements to courses in the following function:

```
def create_model_object(self, course_dict, req, sem):
    semester = Semester.objects.get(season=sem)

    #Checks if the course already exists in the database
    existing_matches = Course.objects.filter(number=course_dict["number"])
    if len(existing_matches) > 0:
        existing_course = existing_matches[0]

        if sem=="spring":
            existing_course.spring = semester
        else:
            existing_course.fall = semester
        existing_course.save()
        c = existing_course

    #Creates a new Course in the database
    else:
        if sem == "spring":
            new_course = Course(title=course_dict["title"],
                        spring=semester)
        else:
            new_course = Course(title=course_dict["title"],
                        fall=semester)
        new_course.save()
        c = new_course

    curr_req = Requirement.objects.get(name=req)
    c.requirements.add(curr_req)
    print(c.id)
```

EDIT 2:

After stepping into the function, this is what I found:

```
def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
    if instance is None:
        return self

    rel_model = self.related.related_model

    manager = self.related_manager_cls(
        model=rel_model,
        query_field_name=self.related.field.name,
        prefetch_cache_name=self.related.field.related_query_name(),
        instance=instance,
        symmetrical=False,
        source_field_name=self.related.field.m2m_reverse_field_name(),
        target_field_name=self.related.field.m2m_field_name(),
        reverse=True,
        through=self.related.field.rel.through,
    )

    return manager
```

And according to my debugger, manager is of type planner(my project name).Course.None.

Comment: You said "it does not work"- what doesn't work? Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Also, can you show us the script that isn't working?

Comment: I edited my original post and clarified what you asked! Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Curious, after that last line (`c.requirements.add(curr_req)`), can you add a line like so: `print c.id, curr_req.id, c.requirements.all()`  and show the output? What you're doing should be working.

Comment: Interesting! I've only been printing before that last line. Off of your suggestion, I tried printing after the last line and it never reaches those statements! I call this function in a loop though and the next iteration starts even though it never prints. So it doesn't seem to be hanging on that line...

Comment: I also tried doing it the other way: curr_req.course_set.add(c) and that still doesn't work

Comment: Have you ever used the `pdb` debugger? I'd be curious to see what's going on. To use it, before your `c.requirements.add(curr_req)` line, add the following line: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. This will drop you into the debugger. When you're in the debugger, you can use the `step` and `next` commands to go through your code one line at a time. In this case, I think you'd want to use `step` once to get into the `c.requirements.add` call, and then use `next` repeatedly to see what's going on... please update your code with the print statement, just so we can rule out something like indentation.

Comment: I actually had already used the PyCharm debugger and stepped in. I edited my post to show what I found.

Comment: @user3699999 Did you ever get a resolution to this? Experiencing the same thing here, so weird. I'm able to perform the `add()` just fine in other model examples, but when I've queried for my objects, it seems just like you, the `add()` doesn't take and the many to many field continues to be empty...Was glad to see my exact same issue and bummed that tis another dead end! Onward!

Answer (score 3):

Verify the last element in the sequence of the joint table and make the update. Django does not throw an error in case the pk already exists.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE schema.table_id_seq RESTART <last_number + 1>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call c.save() after c.requirements.add(curr_req)