# Why is Django's `add()` method in my `many-to-many` Django models not taking?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm, manytomanyfield

## Question / Problem:

I am building a Django app, with 2 models: `User` and `Secret`. Secrets can be made by Users, and other Users can "like" them. I've setup my `likes` field as a `ManyToManyField`, so that Users whom like a Secret can be stored there and later retrieved, etc. However, when I try to query for a User and a Secret and use `my_secret.likes.add(my_User)` *nothing happens*. I don't receive an error and when I print my Secret's `many-to-many` `likes` field, after the add, I see: `secrets.User.None`.

Why is my `add()` method running but I am not receiving any errors, and why is my User not properly being added to my Secret's likes?

**Note:** I've saved both the User and Secret objects upon initial creation. Outside this application I've been able to use the `add()` method just fine, but in those scenarios I was creating objects in the moment, and not retreiving already existing objects.

Is there a different way to handle `add()` when using data retreived from a Query? That's my only other line of reasoning right now, and I've followed the documentation here exactly: [Django Many-to-Many Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships%20*Django%20Docs%20Many-To-Many*)

I also apologize if this was answered elsewhere on the site. I did find one [other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029630/django-many-to-many-relationship-add-not-working), but there was no solution provided, granted they were experiencing the exact same issue.

## My Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    """
    Creates instances of a `User`.

    Parameters:
    -`models.Model` - Django's `models.Model` method allows us to create new models.
    """

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # CharField is field type for characters
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # DateTimeField is field type for date and time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # note the `auto_now=True` parameter
    objects = UserManager() # Attaches `UserManager` methods to our `User.objects` object.

class Secret(models.Model):
    """
    Creates instances of a `Secret`.

    Parameters:
    -`models.Model` - Django's `models.Model` method allows us to create new models.
    """

    description = models.CharField(max_length=100) # CharField is field type for characters
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="secrets") # One-to-Many Relationship
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User) # Many to Many Relationship
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # DateTimeField is field type for date and time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # note the `auto_now=True` parameter
    objects = SecretManager() # Attaches `SecretManager` methods to our `Secret.objects` object.
```

## Problem Example:

The model migrates fine, everything seems to be in proper syntax. However, when I try and retrieve a `User` and a `Secret`, and add the `User` to the `Secret.likes`, the `add()` method gives no errors, runs, but no objects are saved.

Here's an example:

```
tim = User.objects.get(email="tim@tim.com") # Gets a user object
my_secret = Secret.objects.get(id=2) # Gets a secret object
# This is where nothing seems to happen / take:
my_secret.likes.add(tim) # add() method per Django many-to-many docs
print my_secret.likes # returns: `secrets.User.None` -- why?
```

Why when printing `my_secret.likes` above, is nothing printed?

Especially when:
`tim.secret_set.all()` shows the secret containing an `id=2` as in the above example....so the `User` is recording the relationship with the `Secret`, but the `Secret` is not recording any relationship with the `User`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `append` or `update` instead off add

Comment: @hansTheFranz I really appreciate you trying to help me out. I did try just now using `append()` in place of `add()`, and received this error: `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'append'`. I also tried using `update()` and received this error: `TypeError: update() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. Use the exact same formatting as in my post, just replaced the add method with the ones you described! Unfortunately still battling here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *call* the `all`  method of the many-to-many field to view *all* related objects:

```
print my_secret.likes.all()
#                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: ....My friend, the hours I have tormented myself for this LOL, you are an angel from the skies with a message of truth! This worked and is exactly what I was missing! Feeling foolish for how I missed something so basic, and THANK YOU so greatly!! Would give you +1^10000 if I could!!!